# select field where field regexp group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that will select rows based on the fact that the first character in the field is not an alpha.

Example, lets say I have the following data in the table:

```
id | band | song
1 | 3 days grace | song name
2 | avenged sevenfold | song name
3 | as i lay dying | song name
4 | 98 mute | song name
5 | 98 mute | another song name
```

I need this to select:

```
3 days grace (and show a count of 1)
98 mute (and show a count of 2)
```

Here is my code:

```
select band, count(*) as count
from `songs`
where `band` REGEXP '^[^[:alpha:]]'
group by `band`
order by `band` asc
```

This is not working at all.

Comment: Your syntax is correct and the query must work. What is the version of MySQL ? Show us the results you have please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your query in my database and it worked just fine, so the problem is not with the REGEXP but something else. Title and Articles are columns in my database. Interesting how AS COUNT works without count being encapsulated in `.

```
mysql> select Title, count(*) as count 
    -> from `Articles` 
    -> where `Title` REGEXP '^[^[:alpha:]]' 
    -> group by `Title` 
    -> order by `Title` asc;

+--------------+-------+
| Title        | count |
+--------------+-------+
| 3 days grace |     1 |
| 98 mute      |     2 |
+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: you were right it was something wrong in the actual row values themselves. i changed it to use the band slug field and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the field names `Title` and `count` in the first part of the query. Though it appears to work for stephanie gratzer, it might be a problem for your configuration that your field name is a SQL keyword. encapsulating it /might/ resolve this (potential) issue.